# Override use self variables only if they are not defined in Python Class

Tags: python, class

I have a question on Python Classes, is there a more Pythonic way to do the following?

I have a class where I define some class variables, but when I class a class function, I'd like to be able to override some of the variables and if I don't, I'd like to use the 'self' version.

Here is a simple example (in my actual code, my class as a lot of variables that could be overridden hence I want to find a better way to do this):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__ (self, A, B):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B

    def calc_C (self, A=False, B=False):  
        if A == False :
            A = self.A
        if B == False :
            B = self.B
        return A * B

x = MyClass(5, 6)
```

This return 30:

`x.calc_C()`

This return 5:

`x.calc_C(B=1)`

Appreciate any advice. Thank you

Comment: Don't use `False` for unspecified numbers.  In particular, `0 == False` is `True`, which is clearly not what you want.  Use `None` instead, then test with `if A is None:` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many such variables, a decorator might come in handy to do this self-based default operation:

Here is the decorator:

```
import inspect

def selfy(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Extract the "self"
        self, = args

        # Get the parameters the function "func" accepts
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        params = [param for param in sig.parameters if param != "self"]  # ["A", "B"]

        # Make the selfified version of arguments
        selfed_kwargs = {var: kwargs.get(var, getattr(self, var)) for var in params}

        # Call the function with this "selfifed" arguments
        return func(*args, **selfed_kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

And the class will look like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__ (self, A, B):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B

    @selfy
    def calc_C (self, A=None, B=None):  
        return A * B
```

and you can call the method with keyword arguments however you like:

```
x = MyClass(5, 6)
x.calc_C()          # 5*6 = 30
x.calc_C(A=12)      # 12*6 = 72
x.calc_C(B=-7)      # 5*-7 = -35
x.calc_C(A=4, B=9)  # 4*9 = 36
```

**How does it work?**

The decorator `selfy` has an access to how the function of interest is called. All the arguments and keyword arguments are accessible in `*args` and `**kwargs`.

If, for example, we call `x.calc_C(A=12)`, then `args` is a 1-tuple containing `x` instance; and `kwargs` is a dict as `{"A": 12}`. Now, with the help of `inspect.signature`, we access to the function signature (that of `calc_C`) and get the parameter names as a list `["self", "A", "B"]`.

Here, we are interested in explicit parameters i.e. `A` and `B`. Now all we need to do is look at each of these parameters and get their value from the keyword arguments dict passed by user i.e. the dict `{"A": 12}` if it is there; or get it from the `self`. This is what `kwargs.get(var, getattr(self, var))` does.

For example, when `var` is `"A"`, we get `12` as it exists in `kwargs` dict. But for `"B"`, since it does not exist in `kwargs` dict, `.get` returns its second argument i.e. `self.B` (this is by `getattr`).

You might add a lot of variables as you wish to `calc_C`.

Comment: Hi Mustafa, thanks for this. And there's no easier way to do this part:     `A = self.A if A is None else A`    if I have a lot of variables

Comment: Or if I can ask another way, there's no way to write `A=self.A` within the function header...

Comment: hi @ZakZola_, it is not possible to write `A=self.A` because `self` is not defined at function declaration - it is itself another parameter so function has no idea. I wrote a decorator to satisfy this self-based defaulting, please see the edited version.

Comment: Thank you for your help